# part of String contained in a List

Tags: c#

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Create a list with some values from mysql.
2. Search this list with a variable ( I named it `Existed` )
3. If Existed contains a specific string, then do some actions.

Here's a sample of my list data:

```
List ( name users )
Facebook
Google
Yahoo
Strongman
Zombies
Stratovarius
```

If `Existed` inside users contains Strong, then perform some action.

My code so far is below. The problem is that it never enters the action and for some reason I believe it does not see "`Strong`" right.

```
List<string> users = dbm.FindManagers();
foreach (var Existed in users)
{
    if (Existed.Contains(rName_Add_User_result))
    {
        dbm.AddSubuser(Existed, rName_result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is case sensitive. Could that be it? What about the space before and after `Strong`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with case sensitivity, the problem is else, tried and converted all to upper or lower, the problem remains. There are no spaces before and after values this is a field value from a table in mysql

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce. This works for me:

```
var rName_Add_User_result = " Strong ";
//List<string> users = dbm.FindManagers();
var users = new List<string>() {"Facebook", "Google", "Yahoo", "Strongman", "Zombies", "Stratovarius"};

foreach (var Existed in users.Where(u => u.ToUpper().Contains(rName_Add_User_result.ToUpper().Trim()))
{
     //dbm.AddSubuser(Existed, rName_result);
     Console.WriteLine(Existed);
}
```

Result:

```
Strongman
```

Comment: "Can't reproduce" - http://xkcd.com/583/ :)  More seriously I'd throw `Trim` in addition to `ToUpper`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but could be because of case sensitivity. Try converting it to lower and then compare

```
if (Existed.ToLower().Contains(rName_Add_User_result))
{ 
    dbm.AddSubuser(Existed, rName_result);
}
```